# how to search product of woocommerce with product name or title or category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an used YITH WooCommerce AJAX Search plugin but it shows or search keyword from product content also but I want to search product with only the title or product name & category of that product. I have tried & Google but not getting any proper solution.

Please help me.

IN YITH WooCommerce AJAX Search plugin following code is used.

```html
 public function ajax_search_products() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $search_keyword =  $_REQUEST['query'];

    $ordering_args = $woocommerce->query->get_catalog_ordering_args( 'title', 'asc' );
    $suggestions   = array();

    $args = array(
        's'                   => apply_filters( 'yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_search_query', $search_keyword ),
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'orderby'             => $ordering_args['orderby'],
        'order'               => $ordering_args['order'],
        'posts_per_page'      => apply_filters( 'yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_posts_per_page', get_option( 'yith_wcas_posts_per_page' ) ),
        'suppress_filters'    => false,
        'meta_query'          => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_visibility',
                'value'   => array( 'search', 'visible' ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['product_cat'] ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $_REQUEST['product_cat']
            ) );
    }

    $products = get_posts( $args );

    if ( !empty( $products ) ) {
        foreach ( $products as $post ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $post );

            $suggestions[] = apply_filters( 'yith_wcas_suggestion', array(
                'id'    => $product->id,
                'value' => strip_tags($product->get_title()),
                'url'   => $product->get_permalink()
            ), $product );
        }
    }
    else {
        $suggestions[] = array(
            'id'    => - 1,
            'value' => __( 'No results', 'yith-woocommerce-ajax-search' ),
            'url'   => '',
        );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $suggestions = array(
        'suggestions' => $suggestions
    );
```

Comment: Have you checked the WooCommerce documentation?

Comment: @xaviert yes but not get proper solutions..?

Comment: In the premium version of the plugin, you may choose whether the search is to be extended to content (and/or excerpt) and category. Is this not working?

Comment: @masa I have used free plugin